# Remove all vowels in a sentence except for those which occur in the beginning of the word in R

Tags: r, gsub

The intention is to replace all vowels with blank if they are not the first character of word in a sentence.

For Instance, `I AM A HAPPY MINISTER` => `I AM A HPPY MNSTR`. Is there a way to implement this in R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using lookaround:

```
gsub("(?<=[A-Z])[AEIOU]", "", "I AM A HAPPY MINISTER", perl=TRUE)
# [1] "I AM A HPPY MNSTR"
```

This regex searches for uppercase vowels that are preceded by any uppercase letter, then they are replaced by the empty string.

As mentionned in comment by @Jota, another option is to use `\\S` (anything but the space class), which will permit to also remove vowel after hyphen or quote for example:

```
gsub("(?<=\\S)[AEIOU]", "",  "I AM A HAPPY WELL-INTENTIONED MINISTER, D'ACCORD", perl=TRUE)
#[1] "I AM A HPPY WLL-NTNTND MNSTR, D'CCRD"
```

A variant, using parameter `ignore.case`:

```
gsub("(?<=\\S)[aeiou]", "", "I AM A HAPPY WELL-INTENTIONED MINISTER, D'ACCORD", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do

```
x <- "I AM A HAPPY MINISTER"
gsub("([^\\w ])[AEIOU]", "\\1", x)
```

This searches for vowels, which are not after a wordlimit or a space. The vowel is deleted - only the non wordlimit character (or the space) is returned.

Answer (score 2):

We can `SKIP` the words that start with `[AEIOU]` and match the `[AEIOU]` in other parts of the string, replace it with `''`.

```
gsub("(\\b|\\s)[AEIOU](*SKIP)(*F)|[AEIOU]", "", str1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "I AM A HPPY MNSTR"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "I AM A HAPPY MINISTER"
```